# spring-boot Test JpaRepository is null

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to execute a JUnit test restful with spring boot application but it  is wrong. But if I use a browser it's OK!

Help.

**The Repository class:**

```
package com.zhx.help.dao;

import com.zhx.help.model.Girl;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.List;


@Repository
@Transactional
public interface GirlRepository extends JpaRepository<Girl,Integer> {
  List<Girl> findByAge(Integer age);
```

}

**Controller class**

```
package com.zhx.help.controller;

import com.zhx.help.dao.GirlRepository;
import com.zhx.help.model.Girl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class GirlController {

@Autowired
private GirlRepository girlRepository;

/**查询所有女生列表*/
@GetMapping(value = "/girls")
public List<Girl> girlList(){
    return girlRepository.findAll();
}
```

**The JUnit:**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@WebAppConfiguration
public class GirlControllerTest extends MockMvcResultHandlers {

private static Logger log =          LoggerFactory.getLogger(GirlControllerTest.class);

 //模拟对象
 private MockMvc mvc;

 @MockBean
 private GirlRepository girlRepository;

 @Before
 public void setUp() {
     mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new GirlController()).build();
}

@Test
public void girlList() throws Exception {
    RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/girls");
    mvc.perform(request).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

**The code**
https://github.com/longfeizheng/springboot-oracle.git

Comment: Please post your log containing the stacktrace.

Comment: Just `@Autowire` `MockMvc` instead of creating it yourself. You either use the spring managed instance or not. You are starting your application in your test and next don't use it (because you do a `new GirlController()` and use a `standaloneSetup`. With that you are basically ignoring everything you have setup with `@SpringBootTest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current approach you are basically rendering `@SpringBootTest` useless. You are loading everything and the first thing you do in the setup is basically discard all the results.

Either use the started context by autowiring the `MockMvc` or create a simple unit test using Mockito.

### Using a preconfigured `MockMVC`

By simply adding `@Autowired` on your `MockMvc` field you should be able to get the prepared instance and you can simply remove your `setup` method.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@WebAppConfiguration
public class GirlControllerTest {

private static Logger log =          LoggerFactory.getLogger(GirlControllerTest.class);

 //模拟对象
 @Autowired
 private MockMvc mvc;

 @MockBean
 private GirlRepository girlRepository;

@Test
public void girlList() throws Exception {
    RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/girls");
    mvc.perform(request).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

### Create a simple Unit test instead of Integration test

Another option is to not load the whole context and simply directly use Mockito and the `standaloneSetup` you have now.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GirlControllerTest {

private static Logger log =          LoggerFactory.getLogger(GirlControllerTest.class);

 //模拟对象
 private MockMvc mvc;

 @Mock
 private GirlRepository girlRepository;

 @InjectMocks
 private GirlController girlController;

 @Before
 public void setUp() {
     mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(girlController).build();
}

@Test
public void girlList() throws Exception {
    RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/girls");
    mvc.perform(request).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Either way will work and which you need/want depends on your needs and what you want (simply test the controller or make it a huge integration test).

*Note:* You are extending `MockMvcResultHandlers` don't extend that class just use static imports instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create a controller object using new ..
You can do something like below:

```
@InjectMocks
private GirlController girlController;

mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(girlController).build();
```

You can avoid mocking a repository class. Instead create a service class and mock it and access Repository class inside the service class